# Repositories not enabled on fresh boot - is this a problem?

Tags: 18.04, live-usb, repository

I recently created a 18.04.1 LTS Live USB. After setting it up, I noticed several repositories, including universe, were not enabled as they should be. I am aware that this is a known bug for 18.04.1 Subiquity-based Live Server Installer ISOs, however I have not seen any discussion regarding this for Desktop versions. As I am running Ubuntu to detect rootkits and possibly disinfection, is this a bug that I should be worried about? Prior to creating the live USB I ran checksum and no problems there. 
For clarification, I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Comment: A Live USB does not retain data from boot to boot. With a Persistent install you can install programs and data is saved. You do not want to do a general software update on a Persistent install , it will fill even a large drive. You might consider using your Live USB to do a Full install of Ubuntu to a second USB. A Full install can be updated, upgraded, use proprietary drivers, (ie Nvidia), it is more stable and makes better use of disk space than a Persistent drive, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not an issue to be overly concerned about.

Your system will operate fine and you will only run into problems trying to install and update via the package manager.

The repositories are only used for updating and installing the packages on your machine via the internet. While your apt-get install commands will fail saying something about the packages not existing or found, you can still install and update via a USB storage device or Ethernet cable to another machine.

If you re-enable them permanently you are back to a normal system or you can script it to re-enable only when you want to update if you want to only update during specific times.

Or just disable automatic updates.

I was recently working on a project where this was actually part of the system design: all the base system repos were commented out and some custom update repositories were added in to update only the packages we wanted (not my design, just how it was set up before I got there).